# React component children do not mount again when render condition is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A function in `GenericForm` component that performs initial validation updates the `state.errors` field. The component is used from parent component - `AddProjectForm` - with `render()` method:

```
render() {
  ...
  if (this.paramsAreDefined() && this.dataIsFetched()) {
    formElements = fillFormElementsWithInitValues();
    <div>
      <GoBackButtonContainer tooltip={literals.BACK_TO_PROJECTS} />
      <GenericForm formElements={formElements} />
    </div>
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <GoBackButtonContainer tooltip={literals.BACK_TO_PROJECTS} />
      <GenericForm formElements={addProjectFormElements} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The data is fetched asynchronously. The `GenericForm` component is mounted once, without the data, and then when the data is fetched, the component is only being updated.

- Why different returned elements by the `if` statement are not being perceived as mounting a new `GenericForm` component?

I tried using `componentDidUpdate` method to initialize the data, but I get circular dependency error - because the validation function is updating the state.

- How could I go about using the validating function without using the `componentDidUpdate` method?

Thanks!